# com.mongodb.CommandFailureException while connecting to AWS DocumentDB

Tags: java, mongodb, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to connect to AWS DocumentDB from java application. I think I'm able to connect to cluster, not sure... Because earlier I was getting connection timeout and now I'm not. But now I'm getting the below error

java file

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(clientURI);
            DB db = mongoClient.getDB("giftRegistry");
            System.out.println(db);
            System.out.println(db.isAuthenticated());
            CommandResult commandResult = db.getStats();
            System.out.println(commandResult);
```

Getting error in CommandResult line.

Error

```
com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "giftregistry-db.c3ekl0nftuic.us-east-2.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017" , "ok" : 0 , "errmsg" : "Unsupported mechanism" , "code" : 301}
```

Googled up this, but found nothing.

If there is someone who can help, that would be appreciated..!!

Comment: `DB db = mongoClient.getDB("giftRgistry")` might be `giftRegistry`?? is that typo or the reason of the error?

Comment: It's a typo.. updated the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved the problem myself. Earlier I was using **mongo-java-driver-2.12.3.jar**, And I was getting error message:`unsupported mechanism`. Then I googled up about that and found that **SCRAM-SHA-1** is an authentication and authorization mechanism. The `MongoDB 2.x` series did not support SCRAM-SHA-1 and there’s no way to make it work. And, SCRAM-SHA-1 is enabled by default in MongoDB versions beginning with the `3.0 series`. So I replaced the jar with **mongo-java-driver-3.5.0.jar** and It worked out for me